# How will the European requirements for prudent valuation affect derivatives pricing?

Tags: pricing, banking-regulations

The European Banking authority has published the
["EBA consults on draft technical standards on prudent valuation"](http://www.eba.europa.eu/-/eba-consults-on-draft-technical-standards-on-prudent-valuation).

How will these requirements for prudent valuation affect derivatives pricing, if at all?